# Finding Density Function of a Function of other Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions

> Suppose that two electronic components in the guidance system for a missile operate indepen-
>   dently and that each has a length of life governed by the exponential distribution with mean 1 (with measurements in hundreds of hours). Find the probability density function for the average length of life of the two components.

My solution:

Since $\lambda = 1$, $f(y_1) = e^{-y_1}$ and $f(y_2) = e^{-y_2}$ for $y_1 > 0, y_2 > 0$. Since they operate independently, we have

$$
f(y_1,y_2) = f(y_1)f(y_2) = e^{-y_1} e^{-y_2}
$$

The random variable of interest is $U = \frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2}$. As such, we seek the distribution function $F_U(u) = f_U(U < u) = f_U(\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2} < u)$

$$
= \iint_{\frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2}<u}f(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2
$$

$$
= \int_0^{2u} \int_0^{2u-y_1}e^{-y_1} e^{-y_2} dy_2dy_1 = -e^{-2u} -2ue^{-2u} +1
$$

Therefore, we have that

$$
F_U(u) = \begin{cases}
0 & u < 0\\
-e^{-2u} -2ue^{-2u} +1 & u \geq 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

therefore, for $u \geq 0$, 
$$
f_U(u) = \frac{dF_U(u)}{du} = 2e^{-2u} + 4ue^{-2u}
$$

The answer, however, is $4ue^{-2u}$. I don't understand where the extra $2e^{-2u}$ came from. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you computed the derivative incorrectly.
$$\frac{d}{du} (-2ue^{-2u}) = 4ue^{-2u} - 2 e^{-2u}.$$

Comment: Wow, I feel really silly right about now. That would explain a lot. At least I didn't make an error setting up the distribution function.